# IMPDP causing ORA-39002 with no subsequent message

Tags: oracle

In the past, I've seen ORA-39002 followed by subsequent errors providing more detail on the issue. In this case, I get no other information in the console or in the logfile that is created in my directory.

Here is what I see in CMD trying to run an IMPDP command on any dumpfile in Oracle 18c XE:

```
D:\backups>impdp system/<password> schemas=<schema> directory=<directory_name> dumpfile=<dumpfile>.DMP

Import: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon May 2 16:21:19 2022
Version 18.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
ORA-39002: invalid operation


D:\backups>
```

This is a fairly new installation, but I ran an IMPDP in the last few days and it worked without any issues. I don't know of anything that would have changed, and it is a local installation on my workstation that only I use.

Assuming that it might be a file permissions issue, I triple-checked permissions on my dumpfile directory as well as the entry in dba_directories and everything looks fine. In fact, a logfile is created with the following:

```
;;; 
Import: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon May 2 16:17:36 2022
Version 18.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
;;; 
Connected to: Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Master table "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
Job "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully completed at Mon May 2 16:17:38 2022 elapsed 0 00:00:02
Job "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully completed at Mon May 2 16:17:39 2022 elapsed 0 00:00:02
```

I also thought it might be a timezone upgrade requirement since I've seen that issue before as well, but after comparing the version in v$timezone_file to the latest version available I don't think that is it.

My question is what else can cause ORA-39002 besides logfile permissions and time zone issues? Or is it possible that one of these apply in my case and I'm missing evidence of it? I can't seem to find anyone with a similar issue (i.e. console output of ONLY 39002) in all of my searching, so if there is any other diagnostic info that I can provide please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same problem. Finally we discovered that the dump files were corrupt.